# Profile page not displaying user profile information or updating

Tags: php, mysql, database, user-profile

Hope someone can help. I have a profile page that I want to display the logged in users details. So far I have this on the Profile page.

```
<?php  

/* This script pulls the existing name input and displays it when the user logs in. */

session_start();

include("db.php"); ?>

<?php include("includes/header.php") ?>

<?php include("includes/nav.php") ?>




<?php 

    if(logged_in()) {

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if (!$_POST['name'] && $_POST['name']=="") $error.="<br />Please enter your name";
if (!$_POST['email'] && $_POST['email']=="") $error.="<br />Please enter your email";
if (!$_POST['DOB'] && $_POST['DOB']=="") $error.="<br />Please enter your date of birth";
if (!$_POST['country'] && $_POST['country']=="") $error.="<br />Please enter your country";




if ($error) {

                echo '<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">'.addslashes($error).'</div>';

            }

if(isset($_POST['form-control'])) {

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"img/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
 $query = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."'");
}    


    } else {

        redirect("login.php");

    } 

?>


<Style>


.alert{
display:none;
}

#profileimg {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}    

</Style>


<div class="container">
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <!-- left column -->
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar img-circle" alt="avatar" id="profileimg">
      <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>

      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- edit form column -->
  <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
      <strong>Profile updated.</strong>
    </div>
    <h3>Personal info</h3>

    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="edit_profile.php" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label name">name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
         <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" type="text" name="name" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" type="text" name="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">DOB:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['DOB'];?>" type="date" name="DOB" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>" type="text" name="country" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Changes" type="submit">
          <span></span>
          <input class="btn btn-default" id="updated" value="Cancel" type="reset">
        </div>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

```
     <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>

     $("#updated").click(function(){

 $(".alert").hide().show('medium');

     </script>


</body>
</html>
```

I then have another php file for the updating which is this:

```
<?php

session_start();

include("db.php");



$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$DOB = $_POST['DOB'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$password = md5($salt.$_POST['password']);



$query = "UPDATE users SET name  = '".$name."', email = '".$email."', DOB = '".$DOB."', country = '".$country."', password = '".$password."'"; 




$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);




header('Location: profile.php');

?>
```

So the short is it doesn't display or update and I am not sure why. I am new to PHP so go easy on me if this is simple, I have searched but can't seem to find the answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `$_SESSION['id']` assigned?

Comment: also, I need no `form-control` name attribute so `if(isset($_POST['form-control'])){...}` will never fire. Then you're using files but I don't see anything related to that. You're not checking for errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: You have an answer below. Ask them now. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Im also new to this but normally when I check if a SESSION id is active I use

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
$query = "UPDATE users SET name  = '".$name."', email = '".$email."', DOB = '".$DOB."', country = '".$country."', password = '".$password."' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['id']."'"; 
}
```

You also need to echo back the indexed rows that you are trying to query to display results

```
$name = row['username'];
echo $name;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of errors in your code: You are trying to upload a file in the same page whereas you send the form data to another page. How you handle form validation is also a little overhead. What I did change in the form is: I add name="save" in your submit button and added new hidden input for storing your user profile id. I am not sure what login() function did in your code, better stick to if($id){}.

Try this:

```
<?php  

/* This script pulls the existing name input 
   and displays it when the user logs in. */
session_start();
include("db.php");
include("includes/header.php");
include("includes/nav.php");
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
if(loginned()) {//you can do if($id){}  
    $query="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
?>
<style>
.alert{
display:none;
}
#profileimg {
    height: 100px;
    width: auto;
}    
</style>

<div class="container">
<h1>Edit Profile</h1>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <!-- left column -->

  <!-- edit form column -->
  <div class="col-md-9 personal-info">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"
           aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
      <strong>Profile updated.</strong>
    </div>
    <h3>Personal info</h3>    
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" 
          action="edit_profile.php" method="post">    
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label name">name:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
         <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['name'];?>" 
               type="text" name="name" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="text-center">
      <img src="//placehold.it/100" class="avatar 
           img-circle" alt="avatar" id="profileimg">
      <h6>Upload a different photo...</h6>
      <input class="form-control" type="file" name="name">
    </div>
  </div>   
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" 
               type="text" name="email" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">DOB:</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['DOB'];?>" 
                type="date" name="DOB" required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Country</label>
        <div class="col-lg-8">
          <input class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['country'];?>" 
              type="text" name="country" required>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" name="save" 
               value="Save Changes" type="submit">
          <span></span>
          <input class="btn btn-default" id="updated" 
                 value="Cancel" type="reset">
        </div>
      </div>         
    </form>
  </div>
    <?php }else{ redirect("login.php"); }  ?>
```

edit_profile.php First we check whether any post with a name of save is there, We validate the posted data. if validation is successful, we proceed to upload your file and then run your update query.

```
<?php   
    session_start();
    include("db.php");
if(isset($_POST['save'])){
        $id = isset($_POST['id'])? $_POST['id']:'';
        $name = isset($_POST['name'])? $_POST['name']:'';
        $email = isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email']:'';
        $dob = isset($_POST['DOB'])? $_POST['DOB']:'';
        $pass = isset($_POST['passwrd'])? md5($salt.$_POST['password']):'';
        $country = isset($_POST['country'])? $_POST['country']:'';

        if(empty($name)){
            $error = 'Please enter your name';
        }elseif(empty($email)){
            $error = 'Please enter your email';
        }elseif(empty($dob)){
            $error = 'Please enter your date of birth';
        }elseif(empty($country)){
            $error = 'Please enter your country';
        }elseif(empty($pass)){
            $error = 'Please enter your password';
        }else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"img/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
            $query = mysqli_query("UPDATE users SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' 
                                   WHERE id='$id'");
            $query = "UPDATE users SET name  = '$name', email = '$email', 
                      DOB = '$DOB', country = '$country', password = '$password' 
                      WHERE id='$id'"; 
            $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
            header('Location: profile.php');
        }
```

}
    ?>

```
<?php if(!empty($error)){ 
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success 
           alert-dismissable">'.addslashes($error).'</div>';
     }else{
       echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Success</div>';
      }
  ?>
```

I have added a [demo here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9p8i-ykhr). At least this will help:

Comment: thanks so much for taking the time out to help. You are right my code is a mess and I am new so struggling. I have edited my code to what you have done for both files and still nothing is happening. It's not pulling the info or changing it. Any other thoughts? Thanks once again.

Comment: print_r($row) in the first page and show the output in the question.

Comment: just done it. Nothing happened.

Comment: What about the logged_in(). add the code. It will help me figure your problem.

Comment: here's my profile.php code: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5b92a1a5641529a510f8d04f47a90bec906e3dbc 

And my edit_profile.php file: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1bad0009e47848adf35dac0c0234401d732c8f80

any help appreciated.

Comment: I just checked your code and it seems to be fine but the you don't add file upload code inside the form. Does your profile page show up? if it does not, then may be something is wrong your function `logged_in()`.

Comment: No my profile is not showing up. Here is my logged in and user login function: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd2c9bdad758f47c5a854459a16b5c9caff6c468

Thanks so much for taking the time to help.

Comment: See the demo I created for you [here](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9p8i-ykhr).

Comment: That is so nice of you to do that. It still isn't working, can't see why. Very furstrating. What else can I provide to show you that will help solve it.

Comment: Does my demo not work? What error do you get?

Comment: Your demo when placed into my profile.php doesn't work, and that's the weird part there's no error messages??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108091/discussion-between-mawia-hl-and-will).